# How to run your test your application behind VPN on SauceLabs cloud?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cloud, automated-tests, vpn, saucelabs

I want to run UI tests on my application behind VPN on SauceLabs cloud. How can I connect to VPN on SauceLabs cloud? 
Tests are written using Selenium Webdriver and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "[sauce connect](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/)" to provide a tunnel for Sauce tests to get into your local network.

Comment: Thanks, I used sauceconnect and it did the job. To provide more information, you should install and run sauceconnect, then connect to your vpn and then run your tests.