# How to test page load times of a web app from different countries?

Tags: selenium, page-load-time

The company I work for has a web site located in a data center in North America, and would like to test page load times for our site from different continents, specifically from Europe, Asia and Oceania.

How can I do this? I don't know anyone that lives in any of these areas.

I'd love to be able to use selenium to automate this task, and perform various actions, but this is a nice to have.

EDIT: The reason I'd like to test using Selenium is so I can repeat the test from each location hundreds of times, and get an average of what the response time is for pages from my app. I know that these results would be a little fuzzy, but I'm mostly looking for a big picture - for example, it takes twice as long to load page X from Europe as it does from Asia.

EDIT 2: It's been pointed out to me that Google Analytics can be used to get this type of data by Region, which is helpful, but only helps out a little. It's good at helping me identify the big picture, but it's slow at helping me see how things I change affect the load times, which is what I'm really seeking - something that can be run under automation.

Comment: Use the FirefoxDriver along with the Tor browser. You can set the end nodes to specific countries. Since the Tor browser is basically Firefox

Comment: Oh wait that would affect load time a lot.. hmm pretty hard to test actually. Even with vpn connections it will still be slowed down.

Comment: I don't think there's any reliable way of 'testing the load time' it is very variable and even if you were in the country itself it could be faster/slower if you'd do the same things for example 10 blocks away.

Comment: Well after your edit, I still suggest using Tor browser. Even if it slows it down. I think you are able to set the maximum nodes to 1 and then set the end node to your desired country. then repeat for each country x times. Also do that for your home country so you have something to compare it against. I think that is the best (free) solution I can think of.

Comment: @Neijwiert - thanks for the suggestions! I'm definitely open to paid solutions as well as I currently use Sauce Labs to automate testing from different browsers, but can't find any way to use it to test from remote countries, as I thought it might allow.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know any paid solutions. I can give you the code I used for the Tor browser in Java when I get home if you'd like.

Comment: Sure... that'd be sweet! But no worries if it turns out to be too much work...

Comment: Nono not at all. It is from a personal project I was doing, so no need to worry about those pesky copyrights. It is a simple matter of copy and paste to pastebin. Ill post comment here with link. I'm probably home in about 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My webdriver provider interface:

```
package org.gk.networking;

public interface WebDriverProvider
{
    WebDriver requestWebDriver(WebDriverInitialization aInitialization)
            throws IllegalArgumentException,
            WebDriverProviderException;
}
```

Abstract implementation:

```
package org.gk.networking;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.TargetLocator;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public abstract class AbstractWebDriver implements WebDriver
{
    AbstractWebDriver(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver aWebDriver)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if(aWebDriver == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("aWebDriver may not be null");
        }

        this.mWebDriver = aWebDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
            throws Exception
    {
        this.mWebDriver.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public final WebElement findElement(By aBy)
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.findElement(aBy);
    }

    @Override
    public final List<WebElement> findElements(By aBy)
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.findElements(aBy);
    }

    @Override
    public final void get(String aUrl)
    {
        this.mWebDriver.get(aUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public final String getCurrentUrl()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.getCurrentUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public final String getPageSource()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.getPageSource();
    }

    @Override
    public final String getTitle()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public final String getWindowHandle()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.getWindowHandle();
    }

    @Override
    public final Set<String> getWindowHandles()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.getWindowHandles();
    }

    @Override
    public final Options manage()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.manage();
    }

    @Override
    public final Navigation navigate()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.navigate();
    }

    @Override
    public final void quit()
    {
        this.mWebDriver.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public final TargetLocator switchTo()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver.switchTo();
    }

    @Override
    public void webDriverClose()
    {
        this.mWebDriver.close();
    }

    @Override
    public final org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver getWebDriver()
    {
        return this.mWebDriver;
    }

    private final org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver mWebDriver;
}
```

Webdriver interface, since it isn't autocloseable and I cant extend the original since it already has a close method.

```
package org.gk.networking;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.TargetLocator;

public interface WebDriver extends AutoCloseable
{
    WebElement findElement(By aBy);

    List<WebElement> findElements(By aBy);

    void get(String aUrl);

    String getCurrentUrl();

    String getPageSource();

    String getTitle();

    String getWindowHandle();

    Set<String> getWindowHandles();

    Options manage();

    Navigation navigate();

    void quit();

    TargetLocator switchTo();

    void webDriverClose();

    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver getWebDriver();
}
```

Tor webdriver implementation:
    package org.gk.networking;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TorWebDriver extends AbstractWebDriver
{
    public TorWebDriver(FirefoxDriver aWebDriver)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        super(aWebDriver);
    }
}
```

Webdriver initialization interface:
    package org.gk.networking;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public interface WebDriverInitialization
{
    DesiredCapabilities getCapabilities();
}
```

Tor webdriver initialization implementation:
    package org.gk.networking;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TorWebDriverInitialization implements WebDriverInitialization
{
    public TorWebDriverInitialization(DesiredCapabilities aCapabilities, FirefoxProfile aProfile,
            Collection<String> aCommandLineArguments)
                    throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if(aCapabilities == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("aCapabilities may not be null");
        }
        else if(aProfile == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("aProfile may not be null");
        }

        this.mCapabilities = aCapabilities;
        this.mProfile = aProfile;
        this.mCommandLineArguments = (aCommandLineArguments == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(aCommandLineArguments));
    }

    public TorWebDriverInitialization(FirefoxProfile aProfile)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        this(new DesiredCapabilities(), aProfile, null);
    }

    public TorWebDriverInitialization()
            throws IllegalArgumentException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException,
            FileNotFoundException
    {
        this(new DesiredCapabilities(), new FirefoxProfile(getDefaultProfileFile()), null);
    }

    @Override
    public DesiredCapabilities getCapabilities()
    {
        return this.mCapabilities;
    }

    public FirefoxProfile getProfile()
    {
        return this.mProfile;
    }

    public Collection<String> getCommandLineArguments()
    {
        if(this.mCommandLineArguments == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.mCommandLineArguments);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized File getDefaultProfileFile()
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
            FileNotFoundException
    {
        if(TOR_PROFILE_FILE != null)
        {
            return TOR_PROFILE_FILE;
        }

        String torProfilePath = "browsers/tor/profile.default";

        URL resource = TorWebDriverInitialization.class.getClassLoader().getResource(torProfilePath);
        if(resource == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to open " + torProfilePath);
        }

        TOR_PROFILE_FILE = new File(URLDecoder.decode(resource.getFile(), "UTF-8"));

        return TOR_PROFILE_FILE;
    }

    private final DesiredCapabilities   mCapabilities;
    private final FirefoxProfile        mProfile;
    private final Collection<String>    mCommandLineArguments;

    private static File                 TOR_PROFILE_FILE;
}
```

And last, the tor webdriver provider implementation:
    package org.gk.networking;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
import org.gk.PlatformNotSupportedException;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TorWebDriverProvider implements WebDriverProvider
{
    public TorWebDriverProvider()
            throws FileNotFoundException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException,
            PlatformNotSupportedException
    {
        getTorBinaryFile();
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver requestWebDriver(WebDriverInitialization aInitialization)
            throws IllegalArgumentException,
            WebDriverProviderException
    {
        if(aInitialization == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("aInitialization may not be null");
        }
        else if(!(aInitialization instanceof TorWebDriverInitialization))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("aInitialization must be of type TorPhantomJSWebDriverInitialization");
        }

        TorWebDriverInitialization initialization = (TorWebDriverInitialization)aInitialization;

        FirefoxBinary binary = null;
        FirefoxDriver rawWebDriver = null;
        try
        {
            binary = new FirefoxBinary(getTorBinaryFile());

            Collection<String> commandLineArguments = initialization.getCommandLineArguments();     
            if(commandLineArguments != null)
            {
                for(String argument : commandLineArguments)
                {
                    binary.addCommandLineOptions(argument);
                }
            }

            rawWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, initialization.getProfile(), initialization.getCapabilities());

            // Cheaty way to hide window
            //rawWebDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            //rawWebDriver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-4000, 0));

            return new TorWebDriver(rawWebDriver);
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            try
            {
                if(rawWebDriver != null)
                {
                    rawWebDriver.quit();
                }
            }
            catch(Throwable t2)
            {
                t.addSuppressed(t2);
            }

            try
            {
                if(binary != null)
                {
                    binary.quit();
                }
            }
            catch(Throwable t2)
            {
                t.addSuppressed(t2);
            }

            throw new WebDriverProviderException(t);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized File getTorBinaryFile()
            throws PlatformNotSupportedException,
            FileNotFoundException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        if(TOR_BINARY_FILE != null)
        {
            return TOR_BINARY_FILE;
        }

        String torBinaryFilePath;
        if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
        {
            if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_NT || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_95 || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_98
                    || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_ME || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_2000)
            {
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Minimum Windows version required is XP");
            }

            torBinaryFilePath = "browsers/tor/windows/tor_windows32/firefox.exe";
        }
        else if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX)
        {
            if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_CHEETAH || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_PUMA || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_JAGUAR
                    || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_PANTHER || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_TIGER
                    || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX_LEOPARD)
            {
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Minimum OSX version required is Snow Leopard");
            }

            torBinaryFilePath = "browsers/tor/osx/tor_osx64.dmg";
        }
        else if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX)
        {
            String architecture = SystemUtils.OS_ARCH;
            if(architecture == null)
            {
                throw new SecurityException("No permissions to read system property os.arch");
            }

            if(architecture.contains("64"))
            {
                torBinaryFilePath = "browsers/tor/linux/tor_linux32/firefox";
            }
            else
            {
                torBinaryFilePath = "browsers/tor/linux/tor_linux64/firefox";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("The current platform is not supported");
        }

        URL resource = TorWebDriverProvider.class.getClassLoader().getResource(torBinaryFilePath);
        if(resource == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to open " + torBinaryFilePath);
        }

        TOR_BINARY_FILE = new File(URLDecoder.decode(resource.getFile(), "UTF-8"));

        return TOR_BINARY_FILE;
    }

    private static File TOR_BINARY_FILE;
}
```

Hope this is of use to you.

EDIT:
Btw, the profile is a folder that ships with a copy of the Tor browser. Just search for it when you download it. And the binary file is just for example firefox.exe on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use Sauce Labs with a VPN connection, using "Sauce Connect", [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354697/how-to-run-your-test-your-application-behind-vpn-on-saucelabs-cloud)